# Applying a CSS style to a class based on another class on the same level

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a jquery carousel that is applying a class of 'active' to an image that is in a div.  In this same div I also have a span with a class of 'fade' which is applying a css style of opacity: 0;  I am wondering if there is a way either with CSS or javascript to change the CSS style of span class to opacity: 1; when the image (which is on the same level of the span tag) has the 'active' class applied to it.

```
<div> 
     <img src="image1" class="active">
     <span class="fade">
         <p>Text</p>
     </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In CSS use [adjacent sibling selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#adjacent-selectors):

```
img.active + span.fade {
    /* styles here */
}​
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/QBfPg/

Comment: since it's a jquery carousel I guess this should be dynamic. When the active class changed style should be changed.

Comment: @Dasun It will work for dynamic elements: http://jsfiddle.net/QBfPg/1/. Welcome to the world of CSS :)

Comment: thanks so much it works great, i didnt know about the + selector